# How can I get rid of the ticmarks on the x2 & y2 axes of a gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

Here is a picture of the problem I am facing: [Gnuplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMQbp.png)

Additional unlabelled tics appear in my gnuplot on the x2&y2 axis. This is how I have defined the plot:

```
set grid lt -1 lw 0.709
set border 3 lt -1 lw 0.992
set size ratio 0.71
set view 60, 30, 1, 1 
set ticslevel 0.5

#fonts
set title font "IsonormD,16"
#set xtics font "IsonormD,16"
set ytics font "IsonormD,16"
set key font "IsonormD,16"
set xlabel font "IsonormD,16"
set ylabel font "IsonormD,16"
```

after this come only labels and the plot command. Sorry it seems I can't add a picture but would be thankful for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can unset those mirrored tics with

```
set tics nomirror
```

or add the `nomirror` option to your other `ytic` and `xtic` settings.